# Сбивается курсор в div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Ниже скрипт который работает как надо, он помогает мне вставлять элементы в `div` туда, где установлен курсор. А если курсора нет, то содержимое помещается в конец `div`.

Не удобно только то, что если я делаю клик вне области этого блока, то курсор слетает. Я ставлю курсор в нужное место, далее кликаю по значку, чтобы открылась область со смайлами и курсор слетает, смайл вставляется в конец текста в блоке. Если блок со смайлами зафиксирован и всегда виден, то можно установить курсор, кликнуть на смайла и он встанет где курсор, но это не решение для меня.

```js
$(function() {
  var content = document.querySelector('[data-target="insert"]');

  $('.icon-area a').on('click', function() {
    $('.emoji-bar').addClass('hide');
    insertHTML($(this).html(), content);
  });
});

function insertHTML(html, el) {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (elementContainsSelection(el)) {
      if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
          node, lastNode;
        while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
          lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);

        if (lastNode) {
          range = range.cloneRange();
          range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
          range.collapse(false);
          sel.removeAllRanges();
          sel.addRange(range);
        }
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
      }
    } else {
      setEndOfContenteditable(el);
      insertHTML(html, el);
    }
  }
}

function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
  var range, selection;
  if (document.createRange) {
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  } else if (document.selection) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();
  }
}

function elementContainsSelection(el) {
  var sel;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sel.rangeCount; ++i) {
        if (!isOrContains(sel.getRangeAt(i).commonAncestorContainer, el)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    return isOrContains(sel.createRange().parentElement(), el);
  }
  return false;
}

function isOrContains(node, container) {
  while (node) {
    if (node === container) {
      return true;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Я думаю если вы добавите полный пример, где будет воспроизводится описанное, вам помогут быстрее.

Comment: Добавление будет в <div contenteditable="true" data-target="insert"></div>

Comment: Спасибо за помощь всем(

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словами слетает курсор? Должен оставаться фокус на элементе?